# Pig script grouping not possible

Tags: apache-pig

for a web-server log-file example I have a problem with grouping. 
Afters splitting the log-file and doing a projection using:

```
grunt> logs =  FOREACH log_base GENERATE year, month, remoteAddr;
```

I get the following output:

```
(2011,Nov,10.175.120.85)
(2011,Nov,10.116.161.77)
(2011,Nov,10.163.35.206)
....
```

So far no problem. But every grouping like:

```
grunt> grouped_logs = GROUP logs BY(year, month);
```

or a simple grouping only by year, is always getting 0 results. I don't understand why this is not working. My code is the following:

```
grouped_logs = GROUP logs BY(year, month);

counted_logs = FOREACH grouped_logs {
 unique_users = DISTINCT logs.remoteAddr; 
 GENERATE FLATTEN(group), COUNT(unique_users) AS UniqueUsers;};
```

Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0):

Boss are you sure that the data which you are getting in step 1 after for each is correct ? 
i.e.

```
(2011,Nov,10.175.120.85)
(2011,Nov,10.116.161.77)
(2011,Nov,10.163.35.206)
....
```

Because when i loaded the same data and the script you mentioned i am getting the correct result.
The result is as given below,

```
(2011,Apr,1)
(2011,Feb,2)
(2011,Jan,2)
(2011,Jun,2)
(2011,Nov,3)
```

I would suggesst you to re-check the output of "logs"

```
    grunt> logs =  FOREACH log_base GENERATE year, month, remoteAddr;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, great that it is working in your case. But unfortunately not in mine :-(
I am still getting:
(2011,Sept,1)

Comment: sorry, mistake: 
Hi, great that it is working in your case. But unfortunately not in mine :-(
I am still getting:
(2011,Sept,1)
(2011,Sept,1)
(2011,Sept,1)
....
(2011,Oct,1)
(2011,Oct,1)
(2011,Oct,1)
....
without grouping.
grunt> s = SAMPLE logs 0.001;
grunt> dump s;

is returning the correct results: